# Windows create task schedule from command prompt with modified power condition

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, scheduled-tasks, command-prompt

***update:*** I was able to do the highest privilege job with /RL option. (**but still wondering why this is not mentioned in official microsoft documentation?**)

As the title tells, I want to create a scheduled task with modified power condition(untick 'run only when plugged into ac') as we can untick the option in GUI mode, in windows 8.1 with the help of a batch file/command prompt.

I used:

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /tn test1 /tr "C:\Users\SOURAV\Desktop\beautiful_text.bat" /mo 1 /ru ""
```

It created the scheduled task but not with highest privilege. Moreover there were restrictions like 'only run the task when plugged into AC power' etc.

My question is how can I achieve  the same things via command prompt as we can do via GUI?

Another answer in stackoverflow said that it is not possible to achieve all taskes via command prompt as in GUI. But I saw that Opera browser/Google drive automatically created scheduled task in task scheduler and their tasks run with highest privilege. [see image link below]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAu7I.png

Can anyone explain all this things?
Thank you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export as an XML file or create one on the fly with echo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2012-08-19T16:49:14.6182</Date>
    <Author>Serenity\David Candy</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2012-08-19T04:30:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByWeek>
        <DaysOfWeek>
          <Monday />
          <Tuesday />
          <Wednesday />
          <Thursday />
          <Friday />
        </DaysOfWeek>
        <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
      </ScheduleByWeek>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>SERENITY\David Candy</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <IdleSettings>
      <Duration>PT10M</Duration>
      <WaitTimeout>PT1H</WaitTimeout>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe"</Command>
      <Arguments>"C:\Users\David Candy\Documents\Music\Soundtrack\Natural Born Killers [Original Soundtrack]\13 Sex Is Violent.wma"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
    <SendEmail>
      <Server>pop.gmail.com</Server>
      <Subject>Hi</Subject>
      <To>Fred</To>
      <From>DCandy</From>
      <Body>Hello</Body>
      <HeaderFields />
    </SendEmail>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

From Help for `schtasks /create /?`

```
/XML  xmlfile      Creates a task from the task XML specified in a file.
                   Can be combined with /RU and /RP switches, or with /RP
                   alone, when task XML already contains the principal.
```

Comment: I will try it soon and let you know. :)

Comment: I saved the above file in my desktop by name xml.xml and from a elevated command prompt I wrote `schtasks /create /xml C:\Users\SOURAV\Desktop\xml.xml`. But I got `Invalid syntax. Mandatory option 'tn' is missing.`

Comment: Give your task a name. `/tn "alarm1"`. This works here `schtasks /create /tn "alarm3" /xml "c:\Desktop\Alarm2.xml"`

Comment: yes. thank you. :) I figured that out later... :P

One more thing, where can I get detailed tutorial on how to write task xml files? One way is to create task using GUI and then to export to study

Answer (score 4):

This is how to put an xml file in a bat file. Note Skip=6 means the xml file has to start on line 7.

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=6 delims=" %%i IN (%0) DO @echo %%i >>"%temp%\tmp010.xml"
notepad "%temp%\tmp010.xml"
del "%temp%\tmp010.xml"


goto :eof
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2012-08-19T16:49:14.6182</Date>
    <Author>Serenity\David Candy</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2012-08-19T04:30:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByWeek>
        <DaysOfWeek>
          <Monday />
          <Tuesday />
          <Wednesday />
          <Thursday />
          <Friday />
        </DaysOfWeek>
        <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
      </ScheduleByWeek>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>SERENITY\David Candy</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <IdleSettings>
      <Duration>PT10M</Duration>
      <WaitTimeout>PT1H</WaitTimeout>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe"</Command>
      <Arguments>"C:\Users\David Candy\Documents\Music\Soundtrack\Natural Born Killers [Original Soundtrack]\13 Sex Is Violent.wma"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
    <SendEmail>
      <Server>pop.gmail.com</Server>
      <Subject>Hi</Subject>
      <To>Fred</To>
      <From>DCandy</From>
      <Body>Hello</Body>
      <HeaderFields />
    </SendEmail>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```